# Where can I find display cells for a Braille keyboard/display?

Tags: keyboards

I am considering building a Braille keyboard and display from scratch and would like to add note-taking functionality. However, I am unsure where to obtain Braille dot displays as a component. I have noticed that some Braille keyboards come equipped with these displays and would like to include them in my build. If anyone has any information on where to purchase these displays, please leave a comment below.

Answer (score 1):

## Try [this open-source design from Vijay Varada](https://hackaday.io/project/191181-electromechanical-refreshable-braille-module)

[image]

Commercially available individual Braille displays cells typically cost between $100 and $150 each. This is because they use custom piezo electric actuators, which require custom fabrication—an expensive proposition for a low-volume product. While you *could* purchase these cells and make a custom Braille display/keyboard, it will almost certainly be cost prohibitive to have more than a few cells. For reference, [commercially available displays/keyboards](https://www.afb.org/node/16207/refreshable-braille-displays) like the [Focus 40 Blue](https://store.freedomscientific.com/collections/all/products/focus-40-blue-5th-generation) and the [Brailliant BI 40X](https://store.humanware.com/hus/brailliant-bi-40x-braille-display.html) cost *over $3500* for their basic, 40-cell variants; a custom board using these cells will almost certainly be more expensive.

However, since it sounds like you're interested in making your own keyboard, there are more budget friendly alternatives available. This electromechanical design relies on 3D printing and simple CAM actuators to create a far more affordable design. I'd highly encourage you to both watch the project video and read the Hackaday page, but **the key takeaway is that you can have extremely reliable, high-quality modules for a mere $0.82 each**. It's an incredible project, and while it does require some basic fabrication chops, I'd highly encourage you to pursue that route.